# Angular 2 - Can't resolve all parameters for component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-components

I have an error with my shared Communication component after some file structure modification.

> compiler.es5.js:1540 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
>   CommunicatesComponent: (?).
>       at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:60570:34)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73907:35)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73775:26)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73384:24)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73242:25)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73471:54
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:73470:41)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:84666:58
>       at Array.forEach (native)

File structure:

```
app
-- app.module.ts
-- shared/
---- shared.module.ts
---- communicates/
------ communicates.component.ts
------ communicates.service.ts
-- core/
-- feature/
---- feature.module.ts
---- feature.component.ts
---- feature.template.html
-- app.component.ts
-- app.template.html
```

communicates.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { CommunicatesService } from './communicates.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';


import { NgbPopover } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'communicates-popover',
    styleUrls: [ 'communicates.css' ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './communicates.template.html',
    providers: []
})
export class CommunicatesComponent implements OnInit {
    //Communicates objects
    public communicates:Communicate [] = [];

    //Popover 
    @ViewChild('communicatePopover') private communicatePopover: NgbPopover;

    constructor(private communicatesService:CommunicatesService) {         
    }
...rest of code
}
```

shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

import { CommunicatesService } from './communicates/communicates.service'
import { CommunicatesComponent } from './communicates/communicates.component'

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ 
                    BrowserAnimationsModule,
                    FormsModule, 
                    CommonModule,
                   // BrowserModule,
                    ReactiveFormsModule,                                        
                    HttpModule ],
    declarations: [ 
                    CommunicatesComponent
                    ],
    providers:    [CommunicatesService],
    exports: [               
                CommunicatesComponent                
            ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

and app.module when I include shared.module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module'
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module'

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'feature', loadChildren: './feature/feature.module#FeatureModule' }
];
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), 
                    SharedModule, 
                    CoreModule],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    providers:    [],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
    entryComponents: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Regards

Comment: your `BrowserModule` is commented in the imports section of `SharedModule` .

Comment: it must be because I want to use lazy loading

Comment: remove the providers:[] in the component comunicate